# Da dove arriva lo "spiegone"?

Tags: word-usage

Lo spiegone è un termine che sento usare molto di recente.

L'unico dizionario on-line in cui ho trovato la citazione di  questa parola è il [Garzanti](http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=spiegone):

***Spiegone***:

> (fam.) spiegazione lunga e pedante
>   - Etimologia: ← deriv. di spiegare col suff. accr. -one.

Il termine non è presente in Google Books, ma su [internet](https://www.google.it/search?ei=ZUUMWsy1MKXbgAaJmY2ICg&q=lo%20spiegone&oq=lo%20spiegone&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39k1j0j0i30k1l2j0i5i30k1.2374.2696.0.3011.3.3.0.0.0.0.100.255.2j1.3.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.3.255...0i7i10i30k1j0i13k1j0i7i30k1.0.UPvdUjFgdOI) si possono trovare vari casi in cui viene usato.

Qualcuno sa da dove viene questo termine, chi l'ha usato inizialmente e in quale contesto?

Comment: Non risponde alla tua domanda, ma per curiosità è presente anche nell'attuale edizione dello Zingarelli, al termine della voce “spiega” (definito come “spiegazione lunga o prolissa”) e del Devoto-Oli, con voce a sé (“Spiegazione prolissa e pedante”), con 2007 come data di prima attestazione.

Comment: Io l'ho sempre sentito usare abbastanza spesso, ma sono ggiovane [sic] per cui non saprei dire se venisse usato prima del ~2005.

Comment: @DenisNardin Io che sono vecchio ti posso dire che lo sento da almeno quarant'anni ;-) Generalmente unito a "che non finisce più".

Comment: Sull'Internet Archive ci sono al momento [quattro libri](https://archive.org/search.php?query=spiegone&sin=TXT) in cui c'è _spiegone_. Il più vecchio è quello di Gambarotta, del 1996. Come dicevo sopra non è certo di uso recente (direi che più recente è l'uso nel parlato di _pippone_ con lo stesso significato).

Comment: Io (che sono più ggiovane di Massimo e più vvecchio di Denis) non credo di averlo mai sentito in vita mia...

Comment: Non ho una vera risposta, ma utilizzando Google con i range di ricerca temporali si trovano [riferimenti](http://www.cinemah.com/neardark/index.php3?idtit=795) che arrivano già dal novembre 1998 (Google come motore esiste da settembre 1998)

Comment: [Qui](http://smurflandblog.blogspot.it/2010/11/lo-spiegone.html) c'è un divertente raccondo di cosa succede quando lo spiegone si insinua in un corpo umano...

Comment: Io che sono probabilmente il matusa del gruppo, ho sempre usato il termine in ambito familiare, e direi anche che è un termine più del Norditalia. Mio padre era di Roma e non credo l'abbia mai usato.